# vimrc E127: Cannot redefine function CompileBuildrrr: It is in use

Tags: vim

this is some codes in my vim config in .vimrc file below

```
" Compile function
map r :call CompileRunGcc()<CR>
func! CompileRunGcc()
  exec "w"
  if &filetype == 'c'
    exec "!g++ % -o %<"
    exec "!time ./%<"
  elseif &filetype == 'cpp'
    exec "!g++ % -o %<"
    exec "!time ./%<"
  elseif &filetype == 'java'
    exec "!javac %"
    exec "!time java %<"
  elseif &filetype == 'sh'
    :!time bash %
  elseif &filetype == 'python'
    silent! exec "!clear"
    exec "!time python3 %"
  elseif &filetype == 'html'
    exec "!firefox % &"
  elseif &filetype == 'markdown'
    exec "MarkdownPreview"
  elseif &filetype == 'vimwiki'
    exec "MarkdownPreview"
  endif
endfunc

noremap R :call CompileBuildrrr()<CR>
func! CompileBuildrrr()
  exec "w"
  if &filetype == 'vim'
    exec "source $MYVIMRC"
  elseif &filetype == 'markdown'
    exec "echo"
  endif
endfunc
```

input:vim --version
output:VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 29 2020 14:11:37)

Answer (score 3):

It's an error message that happens when we source a file from a function which is defined in that file.

I guess you've defined your function in your vimrc which you're trying to source.

It should be `:source %` BTW if you want to source the current script and not only the .vimrc.

PS: you should have a look at `:h :make` because `!compilername`  is what we had to do some 20ish years ago with the not-improved Vi. Vim has introduced (almost from the start) integrated compilation with the quickfix feature. And given how gnumake is configured on all systems (but mingw), `:make %<`  is enough to compile C++, C, Fortran... For some other languages compiler plugins `:h :compiler`  are also provided by Vim.